# Add kern-font-feature so that it applies to a combination of italic and regular letter-combination

Tags: kerning, font-features

I would like to add the `kern`-font-feature to two fonts so that it covers certain italic and regular glyphe-combinations between the two of them.

I have succeeded in adding them to the regular and italic font of a family and make them apply to certain combinations, but when a combination of italic and regular letters comes up, I can’t get it to work. MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[osf]{libertinus} 
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua
    {fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature 
      {
        name = "ktest",
        type = "kern",
        data =  {
        ["*"] = { ["A"] = -185},
        }
      }
    }

\directlua
    {fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature 
      {
        name = "ktestit",
        type = "kern",
        data =  {
        ["*"] = { ["A"] = -165},
      }
    }
  }

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[
    RawFeature=+kern;+ktest,
    ItalicFeatures={RawFeature={-ktest;+ktestit}}
]

\begin{document}
\emph{*}Apple *Apple

*\emph{Apple} \emph{*Apple}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This yields good results for regular and italic »*Apple«, but when this letter-combination is part-italic, part-regular, it won’t work because the kerning-font-feature doesn’t work across two fonts, as Ulrike Fischer pointed out in a comment. Is there a way to achieve it anyway?

Comment: kerning is a feature of a font it doesn't work across two fonts.

Comment: you could however iterate over the node list in the Lua callback before linebreaking and add kerns between nodes representing the two characters.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: OK, I added that to the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I fear I’m not skilled enough in Lua to turn your comment into an answer. I’ll read a bit about the concepts. Maybe I can figure it out myself.